# Javascript accessing a nested object from ajax response

Tags: javascript, object

[image]

`response._bodyText` works, but I get undefined when I use `response._bodyText.result`

Comment: What do you mean `response._bodyText` works? Can you do `console.log(response._bodyText)`? What do you see? (You might have to JSON.stringify it.)

Comment: Are you using a library for this? XMLHttpRequest itself does not have a `_bodyText` property. If you ARE using a library then you MUST realize that there is an informal coding convention in js that variables that begin with underscore is to be considered private so users MUST NOT USE `_bodyText`. Look at the object's prototype in `__proto`. There must be a method to return the response body. Do not use `_bodyText`

Comment: Better yet, read the library's documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to parse that because its in json format. Try

```
data = JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
data.result
```

For Reference you can study about [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: Thank you.This works. Why doesn't JSON.parse(response) work?

Comment: Because response is just a object. So you don't need to parse it. You can simply access it by key like response._bodyText.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse it

try

```
JSON.parse(response._bodyText).result
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have inside `response._bodyText` is a stringified JSON. 
To access the keys inside of it. you need to first parse it using `JSON.parse`

Example: `JSON.parse('{ "hello":"world" }')`

This will give you an object {hello: 'world'}

In your case you do JSON.parse upon `response._bodyText`, then you can access it just like a normal object.

`JSON.parse(response._bodyText)`

Answer (score 0):

`response._bodyText.result` is `undefined` because `_bodyText` is a string.

You must first turn `_bodyText` into an object:

```
var body = JSON.parse(response._bodyText);
```

After that `body.result` should work.